# What is the difference between "hello".indexOf("") and "hello".indexOf("h")?

Tags: javascript, string

I am currently learning JavaScript where I found a problem that is confusing me. I tried to test `"hello".indexOf("h")`  and the output showed `0` which is logical. However, when I tried this `"hello".indexOf("")` , the output showed `0` . How can an empty string's index is as same as the first letter?

Comment: `"hello".indexOf("he")`, `"hello".indexOf("hel")`, etc. are also at position 0. Is that also a problem?

Comment: I think what I'm trying to say is that all prefixes of a string are at position 0, and the empty string is a prefix of every string.

Comment: This case is addressed in the docs on developer.mozilla.org for [String.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf#return_value).